# Mosaico editing

Tags: mosaico

Mosaico displays editing icons depending on the nature of the text. However when text is to be edited the Format drop down does not include the ability to create bullets or numbered lists. Where are the edit icons configured in Mosaico templates?

Comment: Is anyone able to help. Users want to be able to insert bullets and numbering and it's not available in the verison 2.0 beta2 but on the Mosaico website the format drop downs show the bullet and numbering icons. How can these be made available in the CiviCRM Mosaico extension?

Answer (score 2):

To add bulleted and numbered lists to the Mosaico editor, install the [Mosaico Toolbar Editor](https://github.com/ginkgostreet/com.ginkgostreet.mosaicotoolbarconfig) (com.ginkgostreet.mosaicotoolbarconfig) extension.

Then go to **Administer** > **CiviMail** > **Mosaico Settings**, and edit the **Mosaico Toolbar Settings** field and insert `bullist numlist` after `hr`.

[image]

[image]

Hopefully this might be incorporated into CiviCRM Mosaico one day so that it wouldn't be necessary to install another extension but for now this is how to do it.

Comment: Is this extension compatible with PHP7.1 or above? It seems to only work with PHP5.5+

Comment: Yes - I've had no trouble with using it on PHP 7.2

Comment: thanks, i will try it out, i have PHP7.3

Answer (score 1):

I opened Word, pasted the text I wanted bulleted, then bulleted it, then copied it and pasted it into Mosaico template. The bullets held.

Comment: The Mosaico website shows that Mosaico has under the Format>Block menu the addition of Bullet Lists and Number Lists. It also has a Line Height option. We have just upgraded to the latest version of Mosaico in CiviCRM but these features are not included. The answer above is not ideal and neither is it ideal to enter source mode to use <ul> and <li>. Is there some reason that what is displayed on the Mosaico website cannot be included in the CiviCRM Mosaico extension?

Answer (score 0):

Once the extension is installed here is where to find [TinyMCE identifiers](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/advanced/editor-control-identifiers/#toolbarcontrols)

Answer (score 0):

[Andrew's answer](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/a/31541/35) is great if you can install extensions but you can't code. But if you already have your own extension, you only need these 4 lines of code:

```
/**
 * Hook Mosaico TinyMCE config to add bulleted and numbered lists.
 */                                                                          
function myextension_civicrm_mosaicoConfig(&$config) {
  $config['tinymceConfigFull']['plugins'] = ['link paste lists code civicrmtoken'];
  $config['tinymceConfigFull']['toolbar1'] = 'bold italic removeformat | link unlink | bullist numlist | civicrmtoken | pastetext | code';
}
```

(Replace `myextension` with your extension's short name, of course.)

There's a list of plugins and buttons at:
https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/advanced/available-toolbar-buttons/