# Is there a way to do bullet lists in Mosaico?

Tags: mosaico

One of my clients pointed out that he can't see an option to do bullet lists in 
Mosaico:

[image]

Only option is to go into Source and add `<ul><li>` etc tags

Is there any other way?

Comment: I put this down as a Q to close as there is an answer at https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/18898/mosaico-editing